# what is the correct way to compare two values in property notification?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this simple property which implement property change notification:

```
  public SolidColorBrush Color
    {
        get
        {
            return this.color;
        }

        set
        {
            if (this.color == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            this.color = value;
            this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.Color);
        }
    }
```

I am using Resharper + stylecop. I am getting this warning for above code (on  if (this.color == value) :

```
Possible unintended reference comparison, to get value comparison, use Equals.
```

I used equals as follow:

```
  public SolidColorBrush Color
    {
        get
        {
            return this.color;
        }

        set
        {
            if (Equals(this.color, value))
            {
                return;
            }

            this.color = value;
            this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.Color);
        }
    }
```

Then I am getting warning that:

```
The call to Equals must begin with the 'this','base','object' or linemodel or propertychangeBase prefix to indicate the intended method call (stylecope rule SA1126]
```

So I change it to:

```
 public SolidColorBrush Color
    {
        get
        {
            return this.color;
        }

        set
        {
            if (SolidColorBrush.Equals(this.color, value))
            {
                return;
            }

            this.color = value;
            this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.Color);
        }
    }
```

Now I am getting this warning:

```
Qualifier is redundant.
Access to a static member of a type via a derived type
```

I changed the code to:

```
  public SolidColorBrush Color
    {
        get
        {
            return this.color;
        }

        set
        {
            if (object.Equals(this.color, value))
            {
                return;
            }

            this.color = value;
            this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.Color);
        }
    }
```

No I am getting the warning that (on object.Equals):

```
 Qualifier is redundant
```

So what is the right way to compare these two values? Any standard way to do this comparison that works always correctly?

Comment: is there any property named `SolidColorBrush` in the same scope?

Comment: @pushpraj No, I have a property called Color with this type.

Comment: what I can say is SolidColorBrush does not override Equals so it uses object.Equals implementation, which may give incorrect results, try comparing the underlying color instead

Comment: That `Qualifier is redundant` probably refers to `this` in `this.color`.

Comment: It is just that, **a warning**. Do you want to compare references or the values?

Comment: Just to be very clear, comparing references and values are two different things, you need to decide for each case what it is that you want to do.

Comment: @Default - but the default (per type) is usually prety good. Resharper is also in the snakeoil bussines.

Comment: @HenkHolterman that's my point, the default comparison is usually what you want (i.e. reference comparing). At least that is what **I** want most of the time. I usually just ignore these warnings. Never heard the snakeoil reference :) I guess what you mean is they produce a lot of redundant warnings?

Answer (score 3):

1) `SolidColorBrush` is a reference type and it doesn't  overload `==` operator, so using `==` operator to compare it will do reference comparison. Resharper warns you as you may not know that.

Instead you could do

```
if (this.color.Color == value.Color)
{
    return;
}
```

Note: You need to take care of `null` references.

2) I guess it is style cop's warning(I'm not familiar with this), I'm pretty sure it is same as 3(To avoid confusion later, say which method you need to call clearly).

3) It says that you're calling `Object.Equals` method with `SolidColorBrush.Equals`(derived type). It is not a problem, but later if `SolidColorBrush` adds a `Equals` method with same parameters you'll end up calling a different method which you doesn't intended to do. That's why resharper warns you.

Answer (score 1):

Try sth like this `if (color.Equals(value))`

Comment: Can I use this method on all types? For example value or reference types?

Answer (score 0):

a full comparison from SolidColorBrush could be done by comparing the underlying color struct values by utilizing the Equals overload from Color class

sample

```
    public SolidColorBrush Color
    {
        get
        {
            return this.color;
        }

        set
        {
            if (color != null && value != null)
            {
                if (color.Color.Equals(value.Color))
                    return;
            }
            else if (color == null && value == null)
                return;

            this.color = value;
        }
    }
```